# Padding integers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am interating through `|f|`

```
f.print "ITEM", i
```

`ITEM001`
`ITEM002`
`....`
`ITEM044`
`....`
`ITEM745`

How can I define `i` so that if `i` is 1 it will print 001 always making sure there are  three digits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called padding:

```
5.times do |x|
  puts "ITEM%03d" % x
end
# >> ITEM000
# >> ITEM001
# >> ITEM002
# >> ITEM003
# >> ITEM004
```

Or alternatively

```
5.times do |x|
  puts "ITEM" + x.to_s.rjust(3, '0')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `printf` for this kinds of job, it's flexible enough and easy to remember.

```
5.times do |x|
  printf("ITEM%03d\t", x)
end

#ITEM000 ITEM001 ITEM002 ITEM003 ITEM004
```